# Pandas drop null values - AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dropna'

Tags: python, pandas

For a current project, I am trying to exclude all null values from a numeric table.

When applying the `dropna()` command to "drop" all values not including a number, I am getting the following message: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dropna'`.

Is there any smart tweak to get this running? The corresponding code looks like this:

```
df['Rating_Recommend'] = pd.dropna(df['Rating_Recommend'])
df['Rating_Recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rating_Recommend'])

rating_recommend = df.Rating_Recommend.mean()
print(rating_recommend)
```

Comment: Should be `df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna()`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. This is now yielding the follow-up message for the second line though `ValueError: Unable to parse string "null" at position 10` (position 10 is a null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropna()` is a DataFrame/Series method, not a module's function. So you need to do something like this:

```
df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna()
```

But then, it's pointless to do

```
df['Rating_Recommend'] = df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna()
```

In stead, from your code, you should do this:

```
df['Rating_Recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rating_Recommend'], errors='coerce')

rating_mean = df['Rating_Recommend'].mean()
```

Comment: Nailed it, many thanks. Will accept the answer as soon as it is technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? `df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea - it keeps the message `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dropna'` though

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement to use pd object to call the dropna() function. You can directly use it on the data frame.

```
df['Rating_Recommend'] = df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna()

or 

df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

Check the docs for more options.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea - it keeps the message AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dropna' though

Comment: Try this, this should fix the error: 

df.dropna(subset=['Rating_Recommend'])

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:
`df['Rating_Recommend'] = df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna()`
or
`df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna(inplace=True)` because `dropna` is a method of `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.Series`. In your case, `df['Rating_Recommend']` is a pandas Series.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options to use dropna(), I recommend you check it out!!

```
# Here are all parameters for dropna(). U won't be needing any to just get rid     
#of "Nan" and null values, but they do have useful functionalities  
DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

This should accomplish what your asking:

```
df['Rating_Recommend'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

I hope you check the Doc, you will find it really helpful.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: we don't need self here. Furthermore be careful with the axis and how. This might not be what OP wants. Please explain what you are dropping here.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure! This is just straight of the pandas WebSite, ... just to give him an idea of what parameters dropna(); accepts. The second line Of code is the fixing suggestion, but I see many a contributor already suggested so.